# Background Music addition to HTML page with loops

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I was making a website for a band and then I used the following code

```
<embed src="matrix.m4a" width="180" height="90" loop="true" autostart="true" hidden="true" />
```

in the HTML file and the issue that I am facing is that when I load the page locally the music plays fine but when I browse the website through the internet it gives me a option to download the music matrix.m4a file.

Any fixes o this ?

Comment: Sounds like your server is sending a bad content-type. (Also, you better have a really good reason for doing this...)

Comment: Yes I do - my file has a really automated audio updates which fetches files in .m4a format (PS I tried online conversion but that dint work for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is not aware that the m4a file is in fact a music file, and will send it probably as `application/octet-stream`, which is basically 'hey, please just download this, don't try and open it yourself.'

Perhaps a bit too advanced, but you could make a php script as follows:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: audio/mp4');
readfile('path/to/file.m4a')
?>
```

Final remark as per: only do this if you really think your users will like it. It is considered bad practice to force music on your users, generally.